# Rails actionmailer, send mail at a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails app with actionmailer that sends reminders to customers. So I want to have emails sent at specific datetimes. How can I do that, or any action from the controller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this goal by using some kind of background tasks like [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for example.

Also, gems like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) (Cron jobs in Ruby) would help you get there!

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails) which shows sending emails with a Background Processor through [Active Job](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

#### Update

To send emails at specific date time, you could use [deliver_later](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later) with the `wait_until` option.

```
Notifier.welcome(User.first).deliver_later(wait_until: 10.hours.from_now)
```

Comment: The edit is exactly what i was looking for, much appreciated. Can the "deliver_later" option be edited if the time is incorrect?

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your question, could you please rephrase?

Comment: So say I have called the "deliver later" action.  Can i intercept it if I find out the time is incorrect before the message is sent?